# What happens if the defeating the last monster costs the player their last life point?

Tags: dungeons-dice-and-danger

Players must take away life points when defeating a monster with the heart symbol:
[image]

What if a player ends the game with only 1 remaining life point but must yet suffer 1 life point after defeating the last monster? Does he lose the game?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this does seem to be ambiguous.

Looking at the rules [here](https://cdn.ravensburger.us/content/wcm/mediadata/pdf/alea%20landing%20page/Dungeons%20Dice%20and%20Danger%20Instructions.pdf) is seems losing all your life points does not mean you have automatically lost.

Rules to suggest this.

> The player with the most Victory points wins

and

> A player who loses their last Life point on the Life tracker dies and
> leaves the game.

I'm not convinced 'leaves the game' is the same as 'lost'. especially as a score is still caluble. It looks if you marker reaches end of life tracker then that is -20 points and not elimination.

[image: photo of end of life tracker showing skull and -20 on same space]

If you look at the life tracker image the skull is in the same space as -20,  the others are all distinctly separate.

This however is contradicted by [this](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2880246/defeat) BGG forum question.  One of the answers refers to a designer diary that suggestions many publishers didn't like player elimination.  (I've not found that source directly).  Whether that means the intention in the published version was player elimination I am not clear.   "leaves the game" could easily be interpreted as 'cant win' or 'takes no further part but still has a score'

Comment: Thank you (+1) ! Glad to see you also find it ambiguous. Plus, the rules slightly differ between the french version and the english version of the rulebook!